# Error while publishing an ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

There is a web app I'm trying to make publish in order to upload it by CuteFtp Pro.
I usually being doing this with no problem. But this time, I'm facing crazy error! Actually, as I right-click the solution and click to Publish using File System option choosing an appropriate path for that, finally I got an Error:

**Error**

```
Copying file Images\512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png to obj\Debug\Package\PackageTmp\Images\512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png failed.
Could not find file 'Images\512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png'.
0   0   GiftShop
```

I really don't know and have no idea about this error since there is no file by the name of
`512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png`

In fact, I never had an image by that name through the project!! What could be the reason?
I'm really getting frustrated in challenging with that error.

Anybody could help me on this please?

Thank you so much

Comment: Maybe try editing the project file and searching for the string 512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png and remove any occurrence of it...

Comment: Thanks dear actually I've done that previously but nothing found

Comment: have you checked my solution

Answer (score 1):

This basically happens whenever we delete the contents from the folder but forget to remove from Visual studio solutions.

To Resolve this follow below steps:-

1. Go to visual studio solution explorer and right click on the specific content
2. exclude(yellow marked files) from project.
3. right click and remove those files from visual studio solution explorer.

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the file from your project (right click and exclude).

Comment: it is mentioned in the question that there is no image/file by that name

Comment: lol, you need to click on 'show all files' first. then it will show the missing file as reference. it's a button in the solution explorer top bar

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing exclude your **obj** folder from project.This is the best way for those kind of errors.

In your solution explorer there is one tab with tool tip "Show All Files".Click on it and it will show you all files.

There is one another way

**Update:  went into Project --> Package/Publish Settings, and clicked "Exclude generated debug symbols." The project began publishing with no issue.**

one more solution for you

Are you seeing the file in the project? If so right click and tell it to remove the "ghost" file from the project. Once you do that I would try and publish again.

If its not showing the project, you might be able to create a fake file with the same name (just put some text in there so the size isn't 0kb) and in the same location as the other asp files. Make sure the "show hidden files is selected" and add it to the project and then promptly delete. This would essentially fix the corruption of VS thinking the file exist.

Hope it works.

Comment: You know Rahul the obj folder in my solution is already excluded by defaut. You know as I'm trying all the ways and coming down with no positive result, I copy an Image with the required name (mentioned in the error) into the 'Image' folder but then, another SAME error comes out but this time with another name for image! actually the name of one of my personal images completely regardless to the project!! If I could finally solve the problem I would really like to make a party for that! Such a crazy error is that!

Comment: I don't like to say this, but I already tried that way and not working... I'm trying to explore the scripts for the JQuery slide shows again.. may something found there.. that's really a 'ghost' file!

Comment: I'm so glad to say that, finally I come over the problem! Some time and somehow I used some JS and CSS that were using some images that apparently were deleted from the project. But their 'ghosts' were still living around the project!!! :) What I did to solve the issue was to give them back their body ;) I mean I just created a number of images with the exact names and located them exactly on the expected folder and as if the ghosts just disappear forever! :) But thanks for everyone help!!! Especially 'Rahul'.

Comment: that's great means my last logic is right.so not forget to accepted a answer dear @Ali Ashoori

Answer (score 0):

search for the string name of file in all the files of the project. Remove the line and you are done.

Whats the best guess is that it must have been referenced in one of the CSS you are using especially if you are using Jquery or any of its plugin..

Comment: I've done the search and nothing found but the CSS and JS files may be  good clues for that.. I'm gonna search through them once more.. Thanks for your tip

Comment: js generally don't have some references, but yes i found out files like these in the jQuery plugin pack referenced from the jQuery UI CSS

Answer (score 0):

Look into your solution and exclude this image file, but remember to click on **Show All Files**, and try to rebuild the solution.

**Update 1**

I ran yesterday with the same issue, it was an image not included in the project. Please go to Solution Explorer click on **Show All Files** and check **512px-Icon_-_upload_photo_2.svg.png** image is included in the project or not, if it in gray color so it's not included in the project and if has a yellow icon please remove it from the project.