# Logged error at null.aspx - what us that?

Tags: asp.net, file-not-found

I am having a hard time reproducing an error I have seen in my logs.

It says /app/null.aspx does not exist. And I can't find a way that a user can produce this problem, yet somehow they did several times after signing up.

Any ideas? The trace is:

```
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

EDIT: I seem to have found one tiny hint: I again received this error when trying to log in on a netbook in IE9. The login doesn't work for some reason the client doesn't accept the authentication cookie. No idea why! The same user on a different machine with IE9 and same cookie settings works just fine.

Comment: it means that there is one page name`null.aspx` that is not in your project.try to add that page.

Comment: Nope. There's no reference to any pages called 'null.aspx'..and I cannot for the life of me figure out why users are triggering this. Even typing /app/null.aspx or /app/null handles the page not found error in the global.asax so how can this be logging such an error?

Comment: may be u r facing problem because of `ghost` files try to find your answer on my one link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167031/error-while-publishing-an-asp-net-application/16167172#16167172

Comment: Couldn't see any problems based on that link; still facing this issue though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug with setting image.src=null in javascript. It will still recognise 'null' as a src value and attempt to load it.

In the case of null.aspx I have a rewrite rule adding the '.aspx' bit.

More reference: http://mindfultechnology.wordpress.com/2008/02/03/javascript-imgsrc-null-to-load-or-not-to-load/